# Weird bug in Firefox (Scroll Inner Div)

Tags: jquery, firefox, scroll, scrolltop

Hello there to everyone,

I'm facing a very weird bug in Firefox on a website Im constructing.

I'm using jQuery/GSAP and SmoothScroll in that particular and in some accordions (inner divs) I'm having a lot of information so I've set a fixed height and a scrollbar to them only (the main website has it hidden from default).

In the accordions ONLY in **FIREFOX** while you're scrolling down it goes down, but if you scroll up it continues going down - tested on console log with a script I've found for scroll direction and it always says DOWN.

Now here's my code:

```
isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
// Firefox 1.0+
isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';


if (isChrome) {
  $( '.noscrollz>.vc_tta-panel-body').on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll wheel', function ( e ) {
      var e0 = e.originalEvent,
      delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;
        this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 25;
        e.preventDefault();
});
}

if (isFirefox) { 
      $( '.noscrollz>.vc_tta-panel-body').on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll wheel', function ( e ) {
      var e2 = e.originalEvent,
      delta2 = e2.wheelDelta || -e2.detail;
      this.scrollTop += ( delta2 > 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 25;
        e.preventDefault();
});
}
```

I can't seem to find the issue, can anybody literally help me I've been struggling to understand why the last 6 hours.

Thank you very much in advance, I hope everyone is fine and safe.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

This worked flawlessly (**deltaY** was probably the reason why **Firefox** was bugging).

```
if (isFirefox) { 
    $('.noscrollz>.vc_tta-panel-body').on('wheel', function(e){
        var eventz = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.deltaY*1;
        var top= this.scrollTop += ( eventz < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * -25;
        var bottom = this.scrollBottom += (eventz < 0 ? 1: -1) * 25;
        e.preventDefault();
           //if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0 || e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
                //alert('scrolling up !');
                //e.preventDefault();
            //}
            //if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0 || e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
               // alert('scrolling down !');
                //e.preventDefault();
            //}
    });
}
```